# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un atributo con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Este es mi input y necesito obtener el valor por JavaScript de preferencia que sea puro y no con frameworks o si no hay otra manera ni modo.

```
 <input type="file" name="document8" id="document8" onchange="checkSize(this,1000000);" 
 midamaxima="4000">
```

Necessito recojer el valor de midamaxima passarlo por paramentro a la funcion checkSize o recoger el valor con javascript. No consigo recoger el valor anterior descrito si alguien me puede echar una mano

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿como lo has intentado hasta ahora?  Dices que no lo has conseguido pero no vemos lo que has hecho y no vemos el problema que tienes en tu código. Orientación: Mírate [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) y prueba con eso, y si te da problemas editas la pregunta con tu intento y tu error para que sea una pregunta válida que podamos ayudarte a resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible acceder a todos los atributos del `input` así:

```html
<input type="file" name="document8" id="document8" onchange="checkSize(this, 1000000);" midamaxima="4000">
```

```js
const checkSize = (input, another) => {
  // "input" es un elemento nativo por lo que se puede acceder a todas sus propiedades
  let value = input.value;
  let midamaxima = +input.getAttribute('midamaxima'); // Obtiene el valor del atributo y "+" lo convierte a número
  
  // Logica u operación ...
  
  console.log('Input value: ', value); // fakepath/filename.png
  console.log('midamaxima attr: ', midamaxima); // 4000
  console.log('Another param: ', another); // 1000000
}
```

[Código en vivo | JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m1v80bx/)